# Replacing string in multiple dataframes with lapply

Tags: r

I am trying to replace string in multiple dataframes saved in a list with another string. Below is a representative code for what I need. In the example, I am trying to replace the word "white" with "blue" in dat1 and dat2, but the replacement is not working. Is the issue with my indexing of df.list? I tried indexing the df.list$D in as.character(), but an error pops up.

```
dat1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), c(10, 20, 30, 40),
                   c(100, 200, 300, 400), c("red G white 40 R3", "red G white 40 R5", 
                                            "red H white 40 R7", "red H white 40 R10"))
dat2 <- data.frame(c("red G white 40 R3", "red G white 40 R5", 
                      "red H white 40 R7", "red H white 40 R10"))

colnames(dat1) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
colnames(dat2) <- c("D")

df.list <- list(dat1, dat2)

for(i in 1:length(df.list)){
  df.list[[i]]$D <- lapply(df.list, function(df.list) sub("white", "blue",
                                                                 as.character(df.list$D), fixed = TRUE))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `for` loop **and** `lapply`. Use either of them :

```
df.list <- lapply(df.list, function(x) {x$D <- sub('white', 'blue', x$D);x})
df.list

#[[1]]
#  A  B   C                 D
#1 1 10 100  red G blue 40 R3
#2 2 20 200  red G blue 40 R5
#3 3 30 300  red H blue 40 R7
#4 4 40 400 red H blue 40 R10

#[[2]]
#                  D
#1  red G blue 40 R3
#2  red G blue 40 R5
#3  red H blue 40 R7
#4 red H blue 40 R10
```

Use `gsub` if you want to replace multiple occurrences of `'white'` with `'blue'`.

To get data back to individual dataframes, name the list and use `list2env`.

```
names(df.list) <- paste0('dat', 1:2)
list2env(df.list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This works, but how would I extract the df.list variables back into dat1 and dat2?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `transform` in `base R`

```
df.list <- lapply(df.list, transform, D = sub('white', 'blue', D))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df.list <- map(df.list, ~ .x %>%
                           mutate(D = str_replace(D, 'white', 'blue')))
```